# Buttons, labels, and TextFields are hidden behind image

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, interface-builder

I am planning to create the card game 'War' for ios just to get more practice working with Swift and have a problem. I used the main storyboard to create all the interface objects. Here is a screenshot...

[image]

So I first added an image view and set the image view size as the viewcontroller's view's size and then added a greenish background image. Then I added the labels, text fields, and button. But when I run the app all I see the green background and none of the interface objects. I am thinking it is because the interface items are behind the green background. But it does not make sense because I added the interface objects after the green background.

Anyone know what the issue is and how to solve it? 
Thank you

Comment: Honest question--why are you setting up the UI in code instead of in a storyboard or xib?

Comment: I am setting the code in StoryBoard...not code

Comment: Not if you're calling `myImageview.addSubview(...)` in code.

Comment: If you're doing *both*, then you wind up adding each of those subviews twice.

Comment: Oh ok Now I see what you mean. So now whats happening is that the button and labels are behind AND in front of the background image?

Comment: Yes. To prove that, click on the [square hotdog](http://www.meetup.com/modevdc/events/228589325/) icon to launch [Xcode's view debugger](https://www.objc.io/images/issue-19/xcode-view-debugging-9c452d59.png), then open the view hierarchy in the debugging panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To bring something to the front, simply select it in your storyboard. Click on Editor in the top left corner. Go to Arrange --> Send to Front

Here's a picture of the menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eLRN.jpg

Answer (score 4):

In the view hierarchy, drag your background image to be the first subview of your view. The order of subviews in the tree goes back->front.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was that all the interface items were behind the image view background. And I solved the problem my adding all the interface items as a subview of the imageview, like code below.

```
myImageview.addSubview(myButton)
myImageview.addSubview(myLabel)
myImageview.addSubview(myTextField)
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be due to Image file format. You may need to change from JPG to PNG. In my case it worked.